# Applying different functions to different columns of a Dataset

Tags: dataset

Suppose I have different functions: `Total`, `Mean` and `Max` and the following `Dataset`

```
SeedRandom[0]
dataSet = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c", "d"} -> #] & /@ RandomReal[4, {10, 4}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I do the following: apply `Total` to column `"b"`, `Mean` to column `"a"` and `Max` to column `"d"`, in that order without leaving the `Dataset` i.e. no use of `Normal`? So the result should be

> {22.09, 2.383, 3.765}

Comment: Please confirm that your answer is what you expect. Maybe try restarting your session. I initially got same answer as you, but that's obviously wrong.

Comment: @RunnyKine. You're right, restarting *Mathematica* gave me a different result. I had used a method that was convoluted that gave me that answer. It seemed to work when I tested it, so I don't know what happened there. I will update it now. Am I right to assume there are hidden bugs with `Dataset` as it currently stands.

Comment: @RunnyKine Is it possible to localize this bug?

Comment: @ybeltukov. I don't know, but this is not the first time I've experienced this sort of weird behavior from using `Dataset`. Every time, restarting the kernel solves the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should work and can be easily extended:

```
dataSet[Transpose /* ({Total@#[[1]], Mean@#[[2]], Max@#[[3]]} &), {#b, #a, #d} &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Timings**:

```
dataSet = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c", "d"} -> #] & /@ RandomReal[4, {1000000, 4}]];

(* RunnyKine *)

dataSet[Transpose /* ({Total@#[[1]], Mean@#[[2]], 
      Max@#[[3]]} &), {#b, #a, #d} &]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.968942, Null} *)


(* ybeltukov faster *)

dataSet @@@ {{Total, #b &}, {Mean, #a &}, {Max, #d &}}; // AbsoluteTiming

   (* {1.218837, Null} *)

(* alancalvitti *)

dataSet[{Query[Total, "b"], Query[Mean, "a"], Query[Max, "d"]}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {11.037016, Null} *)
```

Comment: Hm... Do you know why your and OP's results differ from my and @alancalvitti results?

Comment: I have the same table as OP! But summation over the column "b" give me 22.09 even with manual summation. I use version 10.0.1 under Linux.

Comment: @ybeltukov. You're right. I just re-computed it after restarting my kernel and got same value as you. Hmm.

Answer (score 10):

```
dataSet[{ Query[Total, "b"], Query[Mean, "a"], Query[Max, "d"]}]
```

[image]

Can be adapted to association:

```
dataSet[<|"total b" -> Query[Total, "b"], 
  "mean a" -> Query[Mean, "a"], "max d" -> Query[Max, "d"]|>]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

From the documentation

```
dataSet[Total, "b"]
```

> 22.0943

Therefore

```
dataSet @@@ {{Total, "b"}, {Mean, "a"}, {Max, "d"}}
```

> {22.0943, 2.38258, 3.76476}

Faster version

```
dataSet @@@ {{Total, #b &}, {Mean, #a &}, {Max, #d &}}
```

> {22.0943, 2.38258, 3.76476}