# Assign a randomly generated list to variable

Tags: bugs, random, assignment, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

I don't know if this is a silly question, but it really baffles me. So please help me understand this behavior.

```
list=RandomInteger[100,100]
```

I interpret the (silly) code above as randomly generating a list of integers, returning the result and assigning the result to `list`. Please point me out if I was wrong.

But look at what I got by executing the code (after a fresh start of Mathematica V10.0.1 on Windows 8.1) :

[image]

Two results were not identical. It looks like the `RandomInteger` had been re-evaluated to generate a new list.

I then quitted Mma completely and restarted it, trying a smaller list:

[image]

This time two results are identical.

Now I'm really confused. Any suggestion what I did wrong?

Comment: [(61710)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61710/4678) can be related. See the comments there.

Comment: Reported to Wolfram Technical Support. A support case with the identification [CASE:1765387] was created.

Comment: This bug affects all `Random*` functions for the 1D case but not the multidimensional list generation, except for `RandomColor` where it also affects the multidimensional case. I'm on Windows 10 TP.

Comment: @RunnyKine @rhermans I don't know what makes documentations so special. But I found out that if I test them in a doc file, say the doc of `RandomReal`, the output is correct. The `Random*` won't get re-evaluated inside a doc file... Can you confirm?

Comment: Wolfram Technical Support replied confirming that the problem exists on the predictive interface in the front end. Answer updated.

Comment: I **can** reproduce the problem with v.10.0.1 on OS X 10.9.5, **only** when the Suggestions Bar is showed (no bug when the Suggestions Bar is minimized)

Comment: @rhermans From my testing, I only have to disable the suggestion bar feature to get the normal behavior. After all, it is not very predictive, so I think this can be a workaround for the moment.

Comment: @Teake Please check again with the Suggestions Bar turned on.  If that makes the problem manifest (as it did for me) you should delete your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Updated 14-10-2014 see solution at the end.*
*Updated 17-07-2015 Bug no longer present in version 10.2*

*This answer is basically for documentation of the problem.
The credit goes mainly to the people participating in the comments.*

## *Diagnostics*

---

I can reproduce you observation on two different computers both, Windows 7 Pro 64, SP 1 running  Mathematica 10.0.1. The "feature" appears for list of 11 or more random numbers, both using [`RandomReal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html) and [`RandomInteger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html) . I can NOT reproduce the problem on same computer but running  Mathematica 9.0.1, so it may be a new bug.

These are my tests:

### Mathematica 10.0.1

```
list = RandomInteger[100, 11]
```

> `{32, 93, 57, 54, 52, 43, 75, 72, 76, 0, 22}`

```
list == %
```

> `False`

```
list
```

> `{55, 35, 91, 46, 90, 69, 4, 65, 98, 49, 27}`

```
list2 = RandomReal[100, 12]
```

> {4.74866, 2.96541, 45.1146, 51.7122, 15.335, 24.3059, \
>       55.6953, 9.82313, 39.6287, 7.48303, 11.8829, 65.0989}

```
list2 == %
```

> False

```
list2
```

> {72.6577, 86.4083, 24.7092, 93.0095, 66.7453, 20.361, \
>       0.751391, 54.1193, 93.568, 7.31844, 93.3521, 21.871}

[image: Trace output]

No difference for shorter lists

```
list = RandomInteger[100, 10]
```

> {3, 93, 60, 7, 95, 22, 60, 99, 96, 12}

```
list == %
```

> True

Also no problem if evaluated in the documentation notebook

[image]

### Mathematica 9.0.1

```
list = RandomInteger[100, 100]
```

> {40, 4, 94, 60, 85, 10, 91, 74, 4, 30, 88, 29, 46, 36, 13, 79, 52, 96, 71, 18, 20, 13, 36, 62, 98, 48, 88, 20, 92, 75, 6, 92, 11, 90, 85, 5, 66, 35, 21, 57, 69, 86, 20, 91, 18, 94, 100, 74, 37, 1, 8, 86, 14, 79, 43, 78, 30, 0, 3, 16, 94, 95, 27, 68, 56, 51, 33, 80, 62, 69, 60, 45, 70, 61, 30, 59, 37, 97, 29, 97, 14, 23, 8, 10, 99, 23, 36, 75, 83, 8, 31, 97, 89, 31, 90, 5, 56, 71, 80, 67}

```
list == %
```

> `True`

## *Cause*

---

I have contacted **Wolfram Technical Support** and in their reply they say:

> *This is indeed a serious problem and from my testing it looks like*
>   *this happens when the predictive interface is turned on. This at the*
>   *moment seems to be a front-end issue*

## *Solution*

---

This is a bug, so there is no solution for v10.0.1. Based on the answer from Wolfram Technical Support and the comments by @Square1 and @Naitree a temporary workaround is to **disable or minimize the suggestion bar** feature.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `TracePrint` image shows the problem very clearly. No idea why this happens - I suggest you (and @Naitree) report this to Wolfram as a bug.

Comment: This "feature" only shows up for 1D lists. For multidimensional lists generation it doesn't. e.g. `list = RandomInteger[20, {50, 2}]` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is NOT an answer but more like an observation.

Fresh start, win7 x64, MMA V10.0.1 X64:

The first input should assign value to `ans`,
and I check `ans` EQUALS the last output (%1)??

So no problem when you type the first TWO lines together??
[image]

Only is a problem is you type them separately? so executed twice??
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in version 10.0.2. On windows 7, 64 bit

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

try with small list

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could also edit the question and where it says "Introduced in 10.0.0" add "and fixed in 10.0.2".  That way it's immediately clear that we don't need to worry about the bug, without having to glance through all the answers.