# A possible bug with regard to DateObjects in Version 10?

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.1**

Bug related to the [Suggestion Bar Bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62921/assign-a-randomly-generated-list-to-variable)

---

While getting used to the new data type `Date Object` in **Version 10** I noted that there seems to be a bug which on my machine (**Windows 7**) seems to be time-dependent, e.g. `DateObject` will cause an **error after repeated use**.

As an example all of a sudden a simple line like the following:

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 12, 31}]]
```

Will return this error in Mathematica 10.0.1 :

[image: error message]

Starting with a fresh notebook I observe the following:

[image: repeated application]

The first call to `DataRange` will run without any error but after repeated application - note that I had to eventually abort the `Table[ ... ]` expression because it was not done after 5 minutes - the same statement will cause the error.

I also note that there seems to be tremendous **overhead** in using `DateObject`:

[image: overhead]

Has somebody else noted something similar and is this a known bug?

Comment: Your code appears to work correctly here.  Perhaps some resource (packlet) didn't load properly?

Comment: I have not loaded anything consciously besides starting Mma 10. Note, that the code (as shown) will work on my machine without any problems at first; the problem will arise after some time only.

Comment: OK,I have reproduced it (OS X, v.10.0.1). It clearly seems to be related to the (already reported [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62921/assign-a-randomly-generated-list-to-variable)) bug concerning the Suggestion Bar. Try to Minimize/Disable  the bar and make the tests again ... This solution works for me.

Comment: @Square1 Thank you, that seems to indeed resolve the issue which is a definite bug then. With regard to overhead it also seems to pays off to use DateList-form to generate a DateRanges and then Map DateObject to the result.

Comment: The problem still persists in Version 10.0.2 - the suggestion bar needs to stay deactivated.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in 10.1 (or at least is does not occur on a Mac).

Comment: I've updated the bug information in accordance the format [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As kindly posted above by Square1 the error indeed is related to the [Suggestion Bar Bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62921/assign-a-randomly-generated-list-to-variable%20%22Suggestion%20Bar%20Bug%22.) and will not appear if the Suggestion Bar is disabled in the preferences.

What I still find a slight nuisance is the overhead related to `DateObject`:

```
Table[ DateRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 12, 31}]], {1000}]; 
// AbsoluteTiming

(* {67.372854, Null} *)

DateObject /@ Table[ DateRange[ {2014, 1, 1}, {2014, 12, 31}], {1000}]; 
// AbsoluteTiming

(* {28.443627, Null} *)
```

Maybe I am missing something here, but I would expect the implementation to be smarter here?

Comment: The performance gap still persists in 10.0.2